# Additional classes with col or row class?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've recently started coding and I've been warned by my colleague not to apply multiple classes to a div that already has a class of "col" or "row." She said it could cause some issues working with Bootstrap and that I should create another div with the additional classes below the "col" or "row" div.

I want to follow best practices but I can't find anything online referencing this. Is there a hard and fast rule against this or is it a personal preference?

Thanks.

Comment: It's a personal preference and depends entirely on your specific layout and needs. There is nothing inherently wrong with adding multiple classes to an element.

Comment: It is very common to use some classes only for display and other classes for other purposes like declaring usage or purpose. If the added classes don't have css rules they should have no impact when combined with a css framework